# Insertion sort using generics to order an array of values of type T

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, generics, insertion-sort

I'm trying to Implement Insertion sort using generics to sort in ascending order an array of values of type T. The problem is with the for loop, i am getting this error: Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type T and T.

```
namespace InsertionSortTest
{
    class Test
    {
        static public void InsertionSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                T key = array[j];
                int i = j - 1;
                while ((i < 0) && (array[i] > key))
                {
                    array[i + 1] = array[i];
                    i = i - 1;
                }
                array[i + 1] = key;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = new int[] { 2, 3, 7, 1, 8, 5, 6, 12 };
            InsertionSort(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Constrain to IComparable<T> and then use T.CompareTo(T) instead of comparison operators

Comment: (and no, operators cannot be specified with an interface)